# Which fusion tables maps do I need to migrate

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm unsure if the maps I have created through the last years will work when the Google SQL API is shut down January 14th.

I have read about the migration process and I understand it should be straightforward. I don't think so.

Where can I in the code see if I have to change the code?

Some of my maps I have build with the help of the FusionTablesLayer Wizard.
Other maps I have build by using maps and templates I have found and changed. I have made it work, but I won't say I understand everything going on in the code.

I don't see an api key anywhere in the code of my maps. And that makes me unsure if I need to change anything.

Will this for instance work after January 14th:
http://www.kaasogmulvad.dk/unv/fusion/test.html
and what about this:
http://www.kaasogmulvad.dk/unv/3f/projekter1.html

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the examples you reference use the FusionTables SQL API. That is an external API for accessing data stored in FusionTables.  Both of your examples just use the FusionTablesLayer from the Google Maps API v3.